# 'import' operation behaves differently if I name script 'string.py' or 'math.py'. Why it so?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, built-in

**UPDATED:**

**CASE 1:**

files in same folder:

**main.py**

**string.py**

code in **main.py**:

```
import string
```

code in **string.py**:

```
print('Hello!')
```

running **main.py** output is: **Hello!**

**CASE 2:**

files in same folder:

**main.py**

**math.py**

code in **main.py**:

```
import math
```

code in **math.py**:

```
print('Hello!')
```

running **main.py** output is nothing...

**OLD QUESTION:**

If I name my script 'string.py' and import it into another script, it overlaps built-in 'string' module

If I name my script 'math.py' and import it into another script, built-in 'math' overlaps my own one

Behaviour of script import with names like built-in modules depends on how I name them.

Some module names that affected: hashlib, string, calendar

Module names that dont affect: math, cmath, os

From [realpython.com](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/):

> The first thing Python will do is look up the name abc in sys.modules.
> This is a cache of all modules that have been previously imported. If
> the name isn’t found in the module cache, Python will proceed to
> search through a list of built-in modules. These are modules that come
> pre-installed with Python and can be found in the Python Standard
> Library. If the name still isn’t found in the built-in modules, Python
> then searches for it in a list of directories defined by sys.path.

From Michael Lutz's "Learning Python":

> Roughly, Python’s module search path is composed of the concatenation
> of these major components, some of which are preset for you and some
> of which you can tailor to tell Python where to look:
>
> 1. The home directory of the program
> 2. PYTHONPATH directories (if set)
> 3. Standard library directories
> 4. The contents of any .pth files (if present)
> 5. The site-packages home of third-party extensions

So which one is now correct?

Comment: Can you provide sample code that reproduces the behavior you're asking about? You should see the same behavior regardless of the name of the module, which suggests something more is at play here.

Comment: @larsks thanks for answering. I updated question. Should be clear now

Comment: @larsks thanks for answering. I updated question. Should be clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between math and string is that math is written in C for speed purposes and string module is written in Python and can be found under the python lib dir.

So, when you're trying to import string, the local file will override the global string file, but when you try to import math Python will not search for a file, since it's built in the Python interpreter.

You can find the list of all the built-in modules with the following code:

```
import sys
print(sys.builtin_module_names)
```

In case you really want to override math module, you can do so by changing the value in the `sys.modules` dict.

Comment: This doesn't seem correct, at least with Python 3. If I create `math.py` in my local directory and `import math`, I get the local `math.py` file.

Comment: @larsks can you share your full code? a simple "main.py" with "import math; print(math)" with an empty "math.py" works as expected (built-in import).

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that @ZacharyaHaitin's answer is correct, and I am pretty sure that if Karen is actually seeing the behavior described in the question that there must be something else going on.

Let's run through some examples...

### Overriding the `string` module

We have an otherwise empty directory containing two files:

```
$ ls
main.py string.py
```

The file `main.py` contains:

```
$ cat main.py
import string
```

The file `string.py` contains:

```
$ cat math.py
print('hello')
```

When we run `main.py`, we see:

```
$ python main.py
hello
```

### Overriding the `math` module

If we perform the same experiment with `math`, we see the same behavior.  Here is `main.py`:

```
$ cat main.py
import math
```

And here is `math.py`:

```
$ cat math.py
print('hello')
```

When we run `main.py`, we see behavior identical to what we saw in the previous example:

```
$ python main.py
hello
```

The above examples behave identically with Python2 and Python3. In neither case is it necessary to muck about with `sys.modules`.

---

Here is a script that will reproduce the above examples:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Overriding string module"

cat > main.py << EOF
import string
EOF

cat > string.py <<EOF
print('hello')
EOF

echo "main.py"
echo "-------"
cat main.py
echo

echo "string.py"
echo "---------"
echo
cat string.py
echo

echo "Running main.py..."
python main.py

cat <<EOF

======================================================================

EOF

echo "Overriding math module"

cat > main.py << EOF
import math
EOF

cat > math.py <<EOF
print('hello')
EOF

echo "main.py"
echo "-------"
cat main.py
echo

echo "math.py"
echo "---------"
echo
cat math.py
echo

echo "Running main.py..."
python main.py
```

Comment: I've checked, both in Ubuntu and Windows 10 with both versions of Python(2 and 3), no matter is folder empty or not. In case of 'math' I dont get any output. 

As mentioned in realpython.com: " ... If the name isn’t found in the module cache, Python will proceed to search through a list of built-in modules. These are modules that come pre-installed with Python and can be found in the Python Standard Library ... " 

So if I print out sys.builtin_module_names, I see 'math' but don't see 'string'. Neither I see module 'math.py 'in folder of interpreter ('string.py' is present there)

Comment: If you run the test script I've included here and it produces different results for you than it does for me, let me know.

Comment: still the same. In first case - 'hello'
in second - nothing

Comment: But do you have `'math'` in `sys.builtin_module_names`? Because I *don’t*, unlike what the other answer says, and my behaviour is as observed by you. Conversely, if I change the name to `time.py` (and `'time'` is in my builtin modules!), I see the behaviour observed by Karen. So I think Zacharya’s answer is probably correct.

Comment: @KonradRudolph maybe we run different versions of Python interpreter? In my interpreter, module 'math' is included in sys.builtin_module_names

Comment: @KonradRudolph maybe we run different versions of Python interpreter? In my interpreter, module 'math' is included in sys.builtin_module_names

Comment: @Karen Yes, that’s my point: different installations of Python have different builtin modules and, depending on that list, your observed results will differ. That’s why “larsks” wasn’t able to replicate the error, but Zacharya was.